# MDX: Query Performance

Tags: ssas, mdx

This query is taking too much of time for executing result set, is there any way to optimise the query

```
WITH MEMBER PatientName AS [DimPatient].[Full Name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
     MEMBER PatientAge AS [DimPatient].[Age].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
     MEMBER PatientGender AS [DimPatient].[Gender].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
     MEMBER PatientMRN AS [DimPatient].[Medical Record Number].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
     MEMBER PCPList AS  [DimPCP].[Provider Key].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
     MEMBER CareTeamList AS [DimCareTeam].[CareTeamName].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
     MEMBER  ConditionList AS [DimCondition].[Condition Name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
SELECT   (([DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key], 
                   [DimPCP].[Provider Key].[Provider Key],
                   [DimCareTeam].[CareTeamName].[CareTeamName], 
                   [DimCondition].[Condition Name].[Condition Name])) ON 1 ,
{ [Measures].[PatientName] ,
  [Measures].[PatientAge] ,
  [Measures].[PatientGender] ,
  [Measures].[PatientMRN] ,
  [Measures].[Num Of Minutes] ,
  [PCPList] ,[CareTeamList] ,
  [ConditionList] }   ON 0 FROM [NavigateCube] 
  WHERE ( [DimManagedPopulation].[ManagedPopulationKey].&[5059],[DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20160930] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following? There is no need to build measures to return dimension captions. And a `NON EMPTY` should speed it up by returning only combinations of dimensions that make sense (combinations with Num of Minutes I assume):

```
SELECT  NON EMPTY (([DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key], 
                   [DimPatient].[Full Name].[Full Name],
                   [DimPatient].[Age].[Age],
                   [DimPatient].[Gender].[Gender],
                   [DimPatient].[Medical Record Number].[Medical Record Number],
                   [DimPCP].[Provider Key].[Provider Key],
                   [DimCareTeam].[CareTeamName].[CareTeamName], 
                   [DimCondition].[Condition Name].[Condition Name])) ON 1 ,
{ [Measures].[Num Of Minutes] }   ON 0 
FROM [NavigateCube] 
  WHERE ( [DimManagedPopulation].[ManagedPopulationKey].&[5059],[DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20160930] )
```

Comment: displaying empty result set

Comment: @Deepthi what is the main measure in the main measure group which can tell us the valid combinations of patients, PCPs, care teams, and conditions? If not Num Of Minutes then put on the right measure.